# Get orderlines grouped by next two possible shipment dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out in sql, how to select all Orderlines for the next two possible shipmentDate

*Orderlines*

```
    ID  Name       ShipmentDate
    1   Product 1    2019-04-10
    2   Product 1    2019-04-12
    3   Product 2    2019-04-12
    4   Product 1    2019-04-14
```

Desired result

```
    ID  Name       ShipmentDate
    1   Product 1    2019-04-10
    2   Product 1    2019-04-12
    3   Product 2    2019-04-12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `dense_rank()`:

```
select ol.*
from (select ol.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by shipmentdate desc) as seqnum
      from orderlines ol
     ) ol
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Alternatively, you can use filtering in the `where` clause:

```
select ol.*
from orderlines ol
where ol.shipmentdate >= (select distinct ol2.shipmentdate
                          from orderlines ol2
                          order by shipmentdate desc
                          offset 1 fetch first 1 row only
                         );
```